# separating last sentence from a string in R

Tags: r, text, text-mining

I have a vector of strings and i want to separate the last sentence from each string in R.

Sentences may end with full stops(.) or even exclamatory marks(!). Hence i am confused as to how to separate the last sentence from a string in R.

Comment: Something like `sub(".*(\\.|\\?|\\!) ", "", yourvector)`? Provided that there are spaces bewteen your sentences.

Comment: @Scarabee Thanks a lot for your Answer. It's working!! It would be great if you could point me towards a resource for learning text mining in R

Comment: You're welcome. As for the resource, sorry but I don't know text mining (nor R) well enough to give you good advice.

Answer (score 2):

You can use strsplit to get the last sentence from each string as shown:-

```
## paragraph <- "Your vector here"
result <- strsplit(paragraph, "\\.|\\!|\\?")

last.sentences <- sapply(result, function(x) {
    trimws((x[length(x)]))
})
```

Comment: There's just a little problem with this method: you lose the punctuation mark of the last sentence. But I don't know if the OP needs it.

Answer (score 1):

Provided that your input is clean enough (in particular, that there are spaces between the sentences), you can use:

```
sub(".*(\\.|\\?|\\!) ", "", trimws(yourvector))
```

It finds the longest substring ending with a punctuation mark and a space and removes it.

I added `trimws` just in case there are trailing spaces in some of your strings.

Example:

```
u <- c("This is a sentence. And another sentence!",
       "By default R regexes are greedy. So only the last sentence is kept. You see ? ",
       "Single sentences are not a problem.",
       "What if there are no spaces between sentences?It won't work.",
       "You know what? Multiple marks don't break my solution!!",
       "But if they are separated by spaces, they do ! ! !")

sub(".*(\\.|\\?|\\!) ", "", trimws(u))
# [1] "And another sentence!"                                       
# [2] "You see ?"                                                   
# [3] "Single sentences are not a problem."                         
# [4] "What if there are no spaces between sentences?It won't work."
# [5] "Multiple marks don't break my solution!!"                    
# [6] "!"
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex anchors to the end of the string with $, allows an optional '.' or '!' at the end. At the front it finds the closest ". " or "! " as the end of the prior sentence. The negative lookback ?<= ensures the "." or '!' are not matched. Also provides for a single  sentence by using ^ for the beginning.

```
s <- "Sentences may end with full stops(.) or even exclamatory marks(!). Hence i am confused as to how to separate the last sentence from a string in R."
library (stringr)
str_extract(s, "(?<=(\\.\\s|\\!\\s|^)).+(\\.|\\!)?$")
```

yields

```
# [1] "Hence i am confused as to how to separate the last sentence from a string in R."
```

Comment: I tested it and it doesn't work as such, it seems that you have to fix something.